# fullcalendar uncaught typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setoption')

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Js error is thrown when trying to use the setOption method in FullCalendar

> fullcalendar uncaught typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setoption')

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
...
}).render();
calendar.setOption('height', 520);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no requirement to provide the option before the calendar is rendered (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75538516/5947043)).

The problem actually comes from your function chaining.

By putting `.render()` onto the end of the `new FullCalendar.Calendar...` command, you're making it so that the `calendar` variable actually contains the return value from the `render()` function, rather than the return value from the fullCalendar constructor. Since `render()` doesn't return a calendar object (in fact, it [doesn't return anything at all](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/render) - hence the `undefined` problem in the error message), you can't call `setOption` on it.

Simply assign `calendar` directly and call `render()` on it on the next line, and your problem is solved.

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
...
});

calendar.render();
calendar.setOption('height', 520);
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKxGNBV

Answer (score -1):

For FullCalendar 5.0 and later.
setOption should be called before the render function.
For example:

Will cause js error

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
...
}).render();
calendar.setOption('height', 520);
```

Will work

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
...
});
calendar.setOption('height', 520);
calendar.render();
```

Comment: This is not correct or necessary. You have misdiagnosed the cause of the problem - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75802278/5947043)